# Error printing event badges after sorting by participant name

Tags: search-results, pdf, participants, printing

We need to print event badges in alphabetical order instead of the date registered order that you initially get from a participant search.  The PDF creation completes successfully with the default sort, but after changing to alphabetical order, you get a yellow screen DB Error: unknown error.  Is there a way around this?  Thanks!

We are on CiviCRM 5.4.0 on Drupal 7.63

Comment: Could you please edit your question to say what version of CiviCRM you're using? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Larry! One more thing to help folks help you: Go to **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**.  Turn on both "debug mode" and "backtrace", then repeat the steps that caused the error.  The error will become much more detailed.  Edit your question to include the extra details (as text, not a screenshot please!).  The extra detail will help us know what's going on!

Comment: Just tried on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Find participants- event name=????

From results- click on participants heading to order by participant name
Select all
Print name badge

Badges print in search result order.

Just double-checking Is that your process? 

Issue may be fixed in upgrade, or the debug/backtrace may point to another issue in your set up.

Comment: Yes, Craig Almond, that's what I was doing.

Comment: #4..(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.image_URL as `image_URL`, contac...")
#5..[internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.image_URL as `image_URL`, contac...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#8..1907): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, "SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id, contact_a.image_URL as `image_URL`, contac...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9..(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1052 ** Column 'sort_name' in order clause is ambiguous")

Comment: Excerpt above from backtrace which was much too long for the post character limit.  This part seemed to be the most pertinent.

Comment: According to this issue submitted at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/729 If you have a name badge layout with a spacer field and you sort the participants by name prior to generating name badges, the following error occurs.
Column 'sort_name' in order clause is ambiguous 1052

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed that this is caused by having a name badge layout with a spacer field and sorting the participants by name prior to generating name badges.  My work-around for now is to instead of using a spacer in the badge layout, to insert an unused blank field, and I can now print alphabetically sorted badges.